# Poisson process that degrades uniformly

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Given that people arrive according to a poisson process with rate 4 per minute and stay for  $X$~Unif[0,10] number of minutes independently of the arrival times. What is the mean and variance of the number of people after 15 minutes.

I'm attempting this problem. First I noticed that anything before t=5 doesnt matter because anyone would have left who arrived before that. Then the expectation of anyone who arrives in that time period would be $\lambda10 = (4)(10) = 40$  and they all stay with for expected time of 5 minutes. So I would expect that that the epectation would be 20.

I am the same sort of of shotty reasoning for variance which would just be var(possion)*var(X) = $(4^2)(\frac{100}{12}) = \frac{400}{3}$.

However I'm having alot of trouble trying to show any of this formally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting this answer: [Poisson process, number of people in store by time $t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565947/poisson-process-number-of-people-in-store-by-time-t?rq=1)

We are only interested in the distribution of $M(t)$, so we compute this from the joint distribution of $M(t)$ and $N(t)$ by summing over all possible values of $N(t)$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(M(t)=m) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(M(t)=m, N(t)=n)\\
&= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\lambda  t} (\lambda  (1-p) t)^m (\lambda  p t)^n}{m! n!}\\
&= \frac{ ((1-p)\lambda t)^m}{m!}e^{-(1-p)\lambda t}.
\end{align}

More generally, let $X\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,\theta)$, then we compute

$$
p = \int_0^t \frac u\theta\ \mathsf du = \frac t{2\theta},
$$
so that
$$
\mathbb P(M(t)=m) = \frac{((1-t/2\theta)\lambda t)^m}{m!}e^{-(1-t/2\theta)\lambda t}.
$$
This is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu:=(1-t/2\theta)\lambda t$. The mean and variance are both given by $\mu$, so plugging in $\lambda=4$, $\theta=10$, and $t=15$ we have $15$.